# Use a template to get a value and assign a substring of that value to the attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to apply a substring to the value that is returned from calling a template.
This is a working example:

```
        <xsl:attribute name="sportname">
            <xsl:call-template name="sport-mapping">
                <xsl:with-param name="prodParam" select="Sport" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

Let's imagine that sportname gets the value "goal". I only want the first two characters from the start, so I will apply a substring similar to this

```
select="substring(<STRING-TO-MANIPULTE>,2,2)
```

Can you help me achieve this behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the results of the call-template in a variable...

```
   <xsl:attribute name="sportname">
      <xsl:variable name="results">
         <xsl:call-template name="sport-mapping">
            <xsl:with-param name="prodParam" select="Sport" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($results,1,2)" />
   </xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm fairly new to XSLT so it didn't occur to me to separate this tasks into smaller parts